# Как я могу вытащить значения из ключей объектов

Tags: javascript, html, json, объекты, dom

Как я могу вытащить значения из ключей объектов, чтобы их (значения) можно было использовать в DOM как обычные строки?

То есть, я например вытягиваю из первого объекта все значения ключей и уже в дальнейшем применяю их для того же innerHTML. Как я могу это сделать?

```
const arrObjects = [
    {name: 'Georgy', surname: 'Ivanov'},
    {name: 'Geo', surname: 'Iva'}
]

console.log(arrj)
```

Comment: Вам просто надо пройтись в цикле и всё

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arrObjects = [
    {name: 'Georgy', surname: 'Ivanov'},
    {name: 'Geo', surname: 'Iva'}
]
let name = document.querySelector('div');

for (let i = 0; i < arrObjects.length; i++) {
    name.innerText += `${arrObjects[i].name} ${arrObjects[i].surname}`
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: А если например этих ключей со значениями будет в разы больше, вплоть до бесконечности, то каким образом можно всё это вытащить не зная имени ключа?

Comment: Как вы можете не знать имени ключа? Я таких ситуаций на практике не встречал

Comment: Хорошо. То есть если вдруг у меня будет 10 ключей и я буду знать имена их всех (они будут разными), то мне в любом случае нужно обращаться поочерёдно к ${arrObjects[i].name} ${arrObjects[i].surname} и так далее, пока не они не закончатся?

Comment: @dkqr и что это такая за сферическая задача в вакууме, что нужно перебирать все наимования ключей и их значений?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Задачи таковой по сути нет :) Просто пришла мысль в голову и решил задать вопрос

Comment: @dkqr просто от таких абстрактных вещей пользы нет. А в целом, на будущее, если интересует "можно ли сделать N" - всегда ответ "можно"